# Динамическая подгрузка данных к SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: java, android

Хочу чтобы при достижении, скажем 25 элемента, этот самый 25-ый элемент делал невидимыми все свои view, делал видимым `progressbar`, после чего в адаптер подгружались еще 25 элементов.

Вопрос вот в чем: как в `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` четко определить `position` элемента? Через `ViewBinder` не вариант, там ресайзится все постоянно. Если сделать класс наследующий `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`, то я там не вижу метод `getView ()`, на который можно было бы повесить `holder`.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: в `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` вместо метода `getView()` -  [`bindView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java#212) - биндит в айтем данные, его вам и надо использовать для холдера.